# jQuery remove() not removing element

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have some code that removes an item and adds the 3 letter 'app-code' to a cookie, the site then reads this cookie to not draw it next time.

I'm trying to write the code so that the item is removed from the DOM when the user clicks the 'hide button' (which is inside the div I'm trying to remove).

JavaScript

```
$('.HideLinkButton').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var enabled = $(this).hasClass('ButtonToggled');
var favoured = $(this).closest('.Item a').hasClass('btn-favourite');
if (!favoured) {
    if (enabled) {
        removeHiddenLink($(this).closest('.Item').data('application-code'));
        //$(this).removeClass('ButtonToggled');
        $(this).closest('.Item a').removeClass('Hidden');
        $(this).closest('.Item').remove();

        //Adds hidden to class
        $(this).closest('.Item a').addClass('Hidden');
        $(this).closest('.Item').addClass('Hidden');

        //Removes element completely
        $(this).children('.Item').remove();

    } else {
        //Adds application code to 'hidden'cookie.
        addHiddenLink($(this).closest('.Item').data('application-code'));

        //Adds 'buttontoggled' to HideButton div.
        $(this).addClass('ButtonToggled');

        //Removes element completely
        $(this).children('.Item').remove();
    }
}
```

});

For some reason, the last .remove() line doesn't function

I'm talking about this one:

```
$(this).children('.Item').remove();
```

When I refresh the page, the item is gone. This is because it has put the app-code into the 'hidden' cookie, so the C# script knows not to write it to the screen.

It just doesn't remove the element when clicked.

I can't find anything online, or any reason why this shouldn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: can you post the HTML for the button and div

Comment: <div class="Item" data-application-code="DW">

    <a href="thelink" class="btn LinkButton">

        <div><img src="/Content/images/default-icon.png" style="height: 54px;" class="Icon"></div>

        <div>Data Warehouse</div>

        <div class="btn btn-hide Hide disabled HideLinkButton" style="padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px; font-size: 0px"> <img src="/Content/Images/eye.png" alt="favourite" style="height: 18px; width: 18px;"></div>

    </a>

</div>

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how to add code tags, I'm new here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the line to:

```
 $(this).find('.Item').remove();
```

Comment: It doesn't do anything, the issue still applies.

Comment: Can the class .Item not be a child of $(this)? can you try something like  $(this).parent.().find('.Item').remove();

Try moving up the DOM until you can access the class

Comment: Ah! I changed it to .closest('.item a') and it worked! Thank you!